# Take a limited number of items from a potentially infinite generator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

Hypothetically, I have a bunch of generators that never end, like:

> ```
> function* progression() {
>   let n = 0;
>
>   while (true) {
>     yield n++;
>   }
> }
> ```

I want to take first N items from that generator. So I made a function `take` for that:

```
function* take(n, generator) {
  let i = 0;
  let values = generator();

  for (let v of values) {
    if (++i > n) {
      return;
    }

    yield v;
  }
}
```

Is there a better way, maybe standard ES6+ API or a more concise syntax to achieve the same thing? If this function could fail under circumstances that I didn't account for, please give me a hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write it as:

```
function* take(n, generator) {
  let values = generator();

  let i = 0;
  while (i++ < n) {
    yield values.next().value;
  }
}
```

this seems to match the intent more closely though its mostly a matter of personal preference.

#### Update

You can also add the `take` method as an extension to the generator so you could call it like `generator().take(3)`. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47534339/1575353) if you are interested in that approach.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the yielded value can be from `N` (1) to `Infinity` you can use `.next()`, check if the returned object property `done` is `undefined`, if `true`, `break` loop, else `yield` `value`, continue up to `N`.

A second function could also be used to pass a single or different `N` values and "a bunch of generators" to as `rest` parameters, where the return value will be an array of arrays or an object containing a property for each `N` and, or generator.

```js
function* progression0() {
  let n = 0;
  while (true) {
    yield n++;
  }
}
function* progression1() {
  let n = 0;
  while (n < 1) {
    yield n++; // only 1 value yielded from this generator
  }
}
function* take(n, gen) {
  const g = gen();
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    const {value, done} = g.next();
    // break if `done`
    if (done) {break};
    yield value;
  }
}
let n = 7;
let [...a] = take(n, progression0); // individual variable `a`
let [...b] = take(n, progression1); // individual variable `b`
console.log({a, b});
const processProgression = (n, ...gen) => gen.map(g => [...take(n, g)]);
let [c, d] = processProgression(n, progression0, progression1);
// same as `a`, `b` using function to process `N`, and n generators
console.log({c, d});
```

Answer (score 1):

Some minor changes to improve use and protect misuse.

The `take` function only takes from the start. It would be more flexible if you pass the generator, not the generator function. That way you can take from a generator where you left off.

```
function *take(n, values) {    
    while (n-- > 0) { yield values.next().value }
}
```

and then used as

```
take(10, progression()); //to take the first 10
```

Or

```
const values = progression();
take(10, values); // take ten
take(10, values); // take ten more
```

There is a danger someone might use the infinite generator to fill an array

```
const array = [...progression()]; // uncatchable page crash
```

Which is an uncatchable error that will crash the page.

You could create an interface that protects the infinity by hiding the `progression` in closure. You can also then add some extras if need be.

```
const progression = (()=>{
    function *progression() {
        var n = 0;
        while (true) { yield n++ }
    }
    var current = progression();
    return {
        restart() { current = progression() },
        *take(count) {
            current = progression();
            while (count-- > 0) { yield current.next().value }
        },
        *more(count) {
            while (count-- > 0) { yield current.next().value }
        },
        get next() { return current.next().value }
    };
})();
```

And used as

```
progression.take(10); /// get first ten
progression.take(10); /// get first ten again
progression.more(10); /// get ten more
const v = progression.next;  // get next value (21st)
progression.restart();
const first = progression.next;  // get next value (1st)
```